# Magento 2: How to save shipping labels as files rather than in the database

Tags: magento2, shipment, shipping-label

I would like to know if it's possible to store shipment labels inside files rather than directly in a Magento 2 database.

The `sales_shipment` table contains a column called `shipping_label`, which is used to store the labels. These labels are stored as a compressed PDF string that generally starts with `%PDF-1.4`, and ends with `%%EOF`. This string is typically at least 100KB, and so as a result the table is over 7GB in size, is sluggish, and can sometimes crash the frontend of the website when viewing orders with a "MySQL has gone away" error. Furthermore, backups don't always work with it being so large.

If Magento were to instead save these as G-zipped files (or perhaps plain PDF files) and refer to these when required, then the size of the table will drop massively, and the speed will greatly increase.

Is there a way to tell Magento to do this? I've had a good web search but found nothing. Thank you!

Comment: This url may be of value to you, 
    https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-into-outfile/